# Is it possible to remove entry from Bloodhound index manually?

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I'm using typeahead.js's Bloodhound for search. I download all the data once and store it locally, initializing search engine with `local` property equal to that data. Then, the entries from the data can be added or removed. Adding data works well, the library even has [needed API](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#bloodhoundadddata) for that. But removing entries from `local` forces me to call Bloodhound's constructor again, which seems like a bad thing, forcing it to rebuild the index all over again.

So, maybe, there is a hidden backdoor to remove data from `local` and update the index with less cost?